# library DESeq 2 failed

Tags: r

Error: package or namespace load failed for 'DESeq2' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/genefilter/libs/genefilter.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/genefilter/libs/genefilter.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: '/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib'
Referenced from: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/genefilter/libs/genefilter.so'
Reason: tried: '/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib' (no such file)

```
1. Install xcode.
2. Indtal XQuarz
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instruction on this website to install Deseq2: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DESeq2.html

This code is important:

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("DESeq2")
```

Please post more details if it doesn't work.